Strange NumPy output in PyCharm
I'm compiling the exact same code in PyCharm and in CMD, but they're giving me two different outputs:
PyCharm output - [np.float64(1.6000000000000003), -1]
CMD output     - [1.6000000000000003, -1]
I was expecting the same output as CMD gives me in PyCharm, but it gives me "np.float64".
import numpy as np

x_train = np.array([[10, 50], [20, 30], [25, 30], [20, 60], [15, 70], [40, 40], [30, 45], [20, 45], [40, 30], [7, 35]])
y_train = np.array([-1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1])

n_train = len(x_train)                          
w = [0, -1]                                     
a = lambda x: np.sign(x[0]*w[0] + x[1]*w[1])    
N = 50                                          
L = 0.1                                         
e = 0.1                                         

last_error_index = -1                           

for n in range(N):
    for i in range(n_train):                
        if y_train[i]*a(x_train[i]) < 0:  
            w[0] = w[0] + L * y_train[i]    
            last_error_index = i

    Q = sum([1 for i in range(n_train) if y_train[i]*a(x_train[i]) < 0])
    if Q == 0:      
        break       

if last_error_index > -1:
    w[0] = w[0] + e * y_train[last_error_index]

print(w)

I tried reinstalling numpy in PyCharm but it didn't help.
I guess it's PyCharm issue, because in CMD and online compiler i have the same expected output.

Doesn print(np.__version__) give different results in pycharm and cmd?

FlyingTeller is probably on the right track here. This appears to be a difference between NumPy 1.x (no np.float64) and NUmPy 2.x (shows np.float64); the so-called __repr__ presentation for a floating point scalar has changed. So your PyCharm and CMD versions do not use the same NumPy version; they are either different virtual environments, or even completely different Python interpreters.

Note also that there is no practical difference between the two outputs: if you type print(type(w[0]), w[0].dtype), you'll find the same in both cases: w[0] is a NumPy float64. Version 2.x just makes this clearer.
